# Service Fabric Local Cluster Manager not reachable

Tags: .net, azure, azure-service-fabric

Since a few days I'm not able to reach the Manager for my local Service Fabric cluster.

I tried to reset the cluster and even reinstalled it completly (using the latest update), but I'm not able to access it via a browser.

I don't know what happened that it suddenly stopped working.

Chrome:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection localhost sent an invalid
>   response. Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
>   ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Edge:

> Hmm, we can't reach this page. Try this Make sure you’ve got the right
>   web address: https://localhost:19080

Anyone got an idea what else to try?

(Deployments to the cluster work fine though)

Comment: Have you tried http (non-secure) or do you have a secure cluster running locally?

Comment: I tried that. Chrome and Firefox not working. Got it working with Edge now.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem - turns out I had some other applications I was running on localhost and those were binding with SSL on different ports. This caused localhost to end up in the Chrome HSTS set. I cleared it by following these instructions:

1) Go to chrome://net-internals and select “HSTS” from the drop down. Enter the domain name under “Delete domain” and press the Delete button.

2) Now clear your browser cache:

Settings > Show advanced settings… > Privacy > Clear browsing data…

3) Try re-loading the Service Fabric Explorer again!

Answer (score 0):

extracted from the above link (because usually links on SO die at a certain point in time) (https://anhsblog.com/blog/make-chrome-stop-redirect-from-http-to-https/#.WI_EZfkrJaQ)

=====================================================================

Go to chrome://net-internals and select “HSTS” from the drop down. Enter the domain name under “Delete domain” and press the Delete button.

Now clear your browser cache:

Settings > Show advanced settings… > Privacy > Clear browsing data…

That’s it!

Comment: Thanks! Added this to my post.